# Not able to play music file on clicking on Imgeview

Tags: java, android, xml, mp3, android-imageview

I am new to android and not able to figure out why app crashes when i add below code to play music when i tap on Image view (image).
Below is the main activity code.

```
    ImageView one = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cow);
    one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });}
```

Below is the ImageView code in XML file

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
         android:src="@drawable/tr"/>
```

MP3 file is placed under raw folder.
Please help me in fixing this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you find wrong image id.

Comment: Sorry,There is id with button1 ..updated xml

Comment: still app crashing??

Comment: Yes its crashing..

Comment: If i add your code to play file in raw folder..its play on launch, but i want it to play on click of image view and stop when finger is removed

Comment: but i add the code on image click.

Comment: There is no onclick function in your code right?

Comment: yes you just copy from below code and paste in  `onclick()` method.

Comment: It throws error cannot resolve method create..

Answer (score 1):

App crashing because you imageview getting wrong id.
just replace this

```
ImageView one = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

to

```
ImageView one = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.button4);
```

also play audio file from Raw folder:

```
int resID=getResources().getIdentifier("YourAudioFileName", "raw", getPackageName());
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

don't forget to add permission in `Manifest`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Hope it will help you!!